# DOM loading slow with code to wait for jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a Sitecore project where the Javascript libraries are referenced inside components and they would load before jQuery.

[*Consider it as JS library referenced inside .cshtml (MVC)*]

This means the JS file loads before jQuery and this would throw an error in console - `$ is undefined`

[Currently, jQuery is placed at the end of body tag, the usual place.]

To handle this, the custom JS files have this approach to wait for jQuery:

```
var readyForFileA = (callbackForFileA) => {
    if (document.readyState != "loading") {
        callbackForFileA();
    }
    else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callbackForFileA);
    }
}

readyForFileA(() => {
   $(txt).click(function(){
       some_method();
   });
});

function some_method(){
}
```

Now the problem is, there are many such files with similar "wait until jQuery loads" code which is slowing down DOM loading for the pages, as I guess it is going in a loop until DOM loads.

1. Is there a better way to handle this.
2. The simplest way is to move jQuery reference to head, but there are 40 such files where the code has to be updated to `$(document).ready()`
   So, can just this part be modified.

```js
var readyForFileA = (callbackForFileA) => {
        if (document.readyState != "loading") {
            callbackForFileA();
        }
        else {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callbackForFileA);
        }
    }
```

Something like `var readyForFileA = $(document).ready();`

So, that the next part need not change

```
readyForFileA(() => {
   ....
});
```

If not please suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

## Defer Scripts

You can try using the [defer attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) on the scripts, that way they are fetched after the page content finished loading, which will help with page loading performance:

```html
<head>
    <script defer src="./myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

## Window Events

The [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object has lots of events you can use for this. After a quick google search it doesn't seems like jQuery has some event to wait for, that's why i'm going to use the [`window.load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event instead:

```
// Wait for the page to load
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
   // Code to execute once the page has loaded
   $(txt).click(() => {
       some_method();
   });
});
```

Note that you might want want to use other [window events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#events) if your code needs to be ran as soon as possible.

Also note that callbacks are considered bad practice, use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead.